# Why does this goes on an infinite loop? newbie here

Tags: python

I am new here so I hope I can get some help. So can anyone explain to me how does this become an infinite loop?

```
def main():  
    myList = ["abc", "de", "f"]  
    for element in myList:  
        print(element)  
        myList.append(element)  
        print("End")   
        print(myList)  
main()
```

Comment: You keep on appending to same list while iterating the same list `myList`, so never are done iterating all elements from `myList`. Try removing `myList.append(element)`.

Comment: Can you please add details on what are you trying to do?

Comment: Are you just trying to duplicate your list? You could use `myList = myList + myList` instead of doing the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're mutating `myList`, the list you're iterating over, while you iterate over it, by keeping appending `element` to it, so it keeps growing at the same pace you're consuming it, so to speak.

You should iterate over a copy of `myList` instead:

Change:

```
for element in myList:
```

to:

```
for element in myList[:]:
```